# How to calibrate the magnetics sensors?

Tags: java, android, sensors, magnetometer

I wrote a "compass" application to show the result of the measure of the magnetics sensors. It works pretty well, but a function is missing : I dont know how to calibrate the sensors.

I haven't found anything about it in the dev guide. Does anyone know how to enter the calibration mode for these sensors?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Comment: What do you mean to "calibrate"?? Do you want to aim in a different direction of N? to east of something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I now is to [move the sensor in a "8" shape](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22144/magnetometer-shaped-calibration). That's not something you can do programmatically, you can only ask the user to perform that.